# Limit content by a users rank

Tags: php

Basically I'm trying to limit what a logged in user can see depending on what their rank is. The content is several rows, all with different rank requirements. If the user doesn't have the required rank, he will not be able to view that row. **However, my problem here is that if one row has a higher rank requirement than any rows below it and the user does not have that rank, all rows below will not be visible either.**

```
public function Categories() {
    global $Template, $CatArray;

    $CatArray = array();
    $PermissionTable = array();

    $QueryCat = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC");

    while($FetchCat = $QueryCat->fetch_array()) {
        $PermissionTable["category"] = array("id" => $FetchCat["id"]); // store category ID as an id sub-array
        $data = explode(",", $FetchCat["ranks"]); // the ranks row in the database contains all ranks that can see this category, so here we split them up.
        foreach($data as $number) {
            $PermissionTable["category"] += array(
                "rank" => $data // apply rank requirements in a sub-array again
            );
        }

        if(in_array($Template["user"]["user_group"], $PermissionTable["category"]["rank"])) { // here, if the users rank is in the rank sub-array, they will be able to see it
            $CatArray[] = $FetchCat;
        } else { // otherwise display nothing
            $CatArray[] = null;
        }
    }

    $Template["CatArray"] = $CatArray;
    return $CatArray;
}
```

UPDATE: This is what I mean
[image]

Comment: Can you not just add the user current rank to the query like `WHERE rowRank <= userRank`

Comment: No, because the ranks table looks like 1,2,3,4,5 etc so I cant use the <= opreator (its not limiting based on minimum rank required, but what ranks it has written in the table)

Comment: Please show us your database structure, and a real example of what you need to do. For example, user X has 1,4,8 ranks, he needs to see categires a,b and c.

Comment: @BattleMage Updated with image

Comment: Why don't you have a `categories_rank` table? It will be much more easy to find which categories a user could see.

Comment: What I have right now is already really easy, I don't see any point with making a new table with just 2 columns when I can just add a new column into the categories table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some refactor, but in essence, you will use different functions to see if a user can see some category:

```
public function Categories() {
    global $Template, $CatArray;

    $CatArray = array();
    $PermissionTable = array();

    $QueryCat = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id ASC");

    while($FetchCat = $QueryCat->fetch_array()) {
        $categoryRanks = explode(",", $FetchCat["ranks"]); // the ranks row in the database contains all ranks that can see this category, so here we split them up.

        $userCategoriesPermitted = in_array($Template["user"]["user_group"], $categoryRanks); //here we check if user rank is inside category rank

        if($userCategoriesPermitted) {
            $CatArray[] = $FetchCat; //add to return array
        }
    }

    $Template["CatArray"] = $CatArray;
    return $CatArray;
}
```

But this just reflect a poor database design that doesn't follow the [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: This seems to show me categories even if I don't have the required rank.

Comment: My fault. Replace that line with `if(count)` with the new one.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll be sure to keep that article in mind.